# Tweets scraping - how to measure tweeting intensity?

Tags: python, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

I am looking for a method to get information of a "trend" regarding some hashtag/key word on Twitter. Let`s say I want to measure how often the hashtag/key word "Python" is tweeted in time. For instance, today, "Python" is tweeted on average every 1 minute but yesterday it was tweeted on average every 2 minutes.

I have tried various options but I am always bouncing off the twitter API limitations, i.e. if I try to download all tweets for a hashtag during the last (for example) day, only a certain franction of the tweets is downloaded (via tweepy.cursor).

Do you have any ideas / script examples of achieving similar results? Libraries or guides to recommend? I did not find any help searching on the internet. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should check [twint](https://github.com/twintproject/twint) repository.

- Can fetch almost all Tweets (Twitter API limits to last 3200 Tweets only);
- Fast initial setup;
- Can be used anonymously and without Twitter sign up;

here is a sample code:

```py
import twint


def scrapeData(search):
    c = twint.Config()

    c.Search = search

    c.Since = '2021-03-05 00:00:00'
    c.Until = '2021-03-06 00:00:00'
    c.Pandas = True
    c.Store_csv = True
    c.Hide_output = True
    c.Output = f'{search}.csv'
    c.Limit = 10  # number of tweets want to fetch

    print(f"\n#### Scraping from {c.Since} to {c.Until}")
    twint.run.Search(c)

    print("\n#### Preview: ")
    print(twint.storage.panda.Tweets_df.head())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    scrapeData(search="python")
```

Comment: Thank you! This might be what I am looking for. Coincidentally, I just bumped into it so I was looking at it just as you posted it.

Comment: @mieleki install `twint` using `pip3 install --user --upgrade git+https://github.com/twintproject/twint.git@origin/master#egg=twint` else it's showing error [check here](https://github.com/twintproject/twint/issues/1063#issuecomment-742197591)

Answer (score 0):

Try a library called:
GetOldTweets or GetOldTweets3

Twitter Search, and by extension its API, are not meant to be an exhaustive source of tweets. The Twitter Streaming API places a limit of just one week on how far back tweets can be extracted from that match the input parameters. So in order to extract all historical tweets relevant to a set of search parameters for analysis, the Twitter Official API needs to be bypassed and custom libraries that mimic the Twitter Search Engine need to be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I do not think I necessarily need historical tweets but rather "current intensity". The ultimate goal is to get the current tweeting amount. Therefore, I do not even need to have all current tweets (even a fraction is enough) if the method is consistent through time (e.g. gets 10% of tweets within the past hour each time it is called). This way, I could still approximate the tweeting intensity.

Comment: You still can use GetOldTweets library for your purpose. The GetOldTweets is able to bypass Twitter Streaming API restrictions. Just give it a try.